# How can I find customers without any entries with an email?

Tags: mysql, select

I have this table:

| line | account | name | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | Reyes VonRueden Sr. |  |
| 1 | 1000 | Dr. Elena Bartell V |  |
| 1 | 1000 | Lucio Wehner | sharon51@yahooo.com |
| 2 | 1000 | April Hansen |  |
| 2 | 1000 | Amy Waelchi | hegmann.khalid@yahooo.com |
| 2 | 1000 | Tremaine Cassin |  |
| 3 | 1000 | Susana White Jr. |  |
| 3 | 1000 | Roxane Hoeger | jfay@hotmailses.com |
| 3 | 1000 | Prof. Eric Boehm |  |
| **4** | **1000** | **Miles Considine** |  |
| **4** | **1000** | **Araceli Effertz** |  |
| **4** | **1000** | **Prof. Adolph Pacocha** |  |
| 5 | 1000 | Prof. Rafaela Hills | sydney20@gradyesses.com |
| 5 | 1000 | Delta Becker |  |
| 5 | 1000 | Aditya Ratke | julian28@yahooes.com |
| 6 | 1000 | Miss Elaina Aufderhar Sr. | royal.predovic@connellyses.com |
| 6 | 1000 | Miss Stephanie Russel IV |  |
| 6 | 1000 | Dr. Ramiro Marks IV | wrice@yahooes.com |
| **7** | **1000** | **Garfield Kozey** |  |
| **7** | **1000** | **Gene Hilpert** |  |

The combinations of line and account define a customer. (The name field is a worker and not relevant).

I am looking for customers (line + account) whose does not have any entries with an email address in the field email.

The expected result for the table above is 4-1000 and 7-1000.

I can solve it with 2 queries and using excel. But how do I do that in MySQL?

Comment: I hope these are not real names/email. But if so please edit/remove them.

Comment: no it's not real... it's generated by random generator.

Comment: "whose name field does not have an email address" - what does that mean? None of the name columns contain a mail address. Also, share your attempts to resolve the problem - anything not working with a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: sorry my english is not so good....
So as you can see the only good results are write with bold font. Only the 7-1000 and 4-1000 is the good results for the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(line, '-', account)
FROM customer
WHERE CONCAT(line, '-', account) NOT IN (SELECT CONCAT(line, '-', account)
                                        FROM customer
                                        WHERE email LIKE '%@%');
```

The expected result would be:

| CONCAT(line,'-', account) |
| --- |
| 4-1000 |
| 7-1000 |

How does it work?

1. The "inner" SQL in the brackets select every customer (which consists of a unique line + account field combination) that does have an email.
2. The "outer" SQL then selects every account that is not in that list and thus does not have any entry with an email.

The `CONCAT()` is more of a cosmetic, you could write the SQL without, but you'd need to do a bit of fiddling because the outer condition is a combination of two columns.

Alternatively, one could do a `OUTER JOIN` on the same table, but this form is a bit clearer on what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query you're looking for.

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE email IS NULL or email = '';
```

This query will give you all fields that do not have an email.

If you're however looking for records that do not have a valid email address, then use the query below.

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE email not like '%@%';
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i'm not searching for empty fields i'm searching for costumer (line+account) who hasn't any email addresses in the email field. I think i need a double select query somehow.

Comment: Then we can change the query like SELECT line, account FROM customer WHERE email IS NULL or email = '';

This will return line and account for anyone without an email address.

Comment: I believe nzoli means that he wants only the _accounts_ where none of the entries has an email. This approach would give us each _entry_ with email.

Comment: yes exatly, sorry for my english :)
In this case the good results are: 4-1000 and 7-1000.

Comment: In that case, let's use this query to return "only the accounts where none of the entries has an email" 
SELECT concat(line, '-', account) as account from customer where email is not like '%@%' group by line, account;

Comment: Not good because e.g. the 1-1000 having an empty email field but is still not good. Only the 4-1000 ant 7-1000 are goods.

Comment: Which means we can identify 4-1000 and 7-1000 as products because they have an asterisk in the email field?
If that's the case, here is the query for that.

SELECT concat(line,'-',account) AS product FROM customer WHERE email like '%*%' and email not like '%@%' group by line, account;

Comment: Sorry the asterisk is my edit error. I have no asterisk in my real table.